# pytorch: sum of cross entropy over all classes

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to compute sum of cross entropy over all classes for each prediction, where the input is batch (size n), and the output is batch (size n).

[image]

The simplest way is for loop (for 1000 classes):

```
def sum_of_CE_lost(input):
    L = 0
    for c in range(1000):
        L = L + torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(input, c)
    return L
```

However, it is very slow. What is a better way? How can we parallelized it for GPU (CUDA)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
torch.nn.functional.log_softmax (input).sum() / input.shape[0]
```

We divide by input.shape[0] because cross_entropy() takes, by default the mean across the batch dimension.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to make it faster, you need to vectorize it, that is, work with matrices.

So, image you have 1,000 samples to compute the loss. Also, your classification problem has 5 labels. To compute the `CrossEntropyLoss` we need an input and a target. Let's simulate that as follows:

```
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss() # the loss function
input = torch.randn(1000, 5) #1000 samples and 5 labels' predictions
target = torch.empty(1000, dtype=torch.long).random_(5) # 1000 samples with labels from 0 to 4
loss_value = loss(input, target) # It'll output the loss
```

There we go! Now the loss is computed considering the 1,000 samples. This is the fatest way to do that.

Comment: in your code, the target should be target = torch.tensor(np.tile(np.arange(5), (1000, 1))). Then we get "RuntimeError: 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported"